# Jmeter write to file -Beanshell script issues

Tags: jmeter

I am writing my variables to a CSV file but I am facing these 2 issues-
1. Even if the script finishes, the CSV file displays it is in use and read only mode
2. I want to have tab separated values but \t in following does not work

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\path to csv\\test.csv",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(vars.get("num1"));
out.write(System.getProperty("\t"));
out.write(vars.get("num2"));

out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.close();
fstream.close();
```

What do I do to fix them?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can try writing something like the one mentioned in [this blog](https://hellotestworld.com/2013/05/02/write-a-file-from-a-jmeter-script/). Maybe it helps.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

// Get the variable(s) from the JMeter script
tempVar = vars.get("ExampleVar");

// Static elements or calculations
part1 = "Car Speed is: ";
part2 = " km/h";

// Open File(s)
f = new FileOutputStream(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()+"\\carSpeed.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 

// Write data to file 
p.println( part1 + tempVar + part2 );

// Close File(s)
p.close();f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
out.write(System.getProperty("\t"));
```

with

```
out.write("\t");
```

This causes your script failure on that line hence "num2" variable isn't being written and stream is not closed.

Next time you experience a problem with Beanshell script take a look into *jmeter.log* file for any errors. If you want a human-readable stacktrace - surround your code with try/catch block like:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Something wrong", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using and troubleshooting Beanshell scripts.

---

By the way, you can write any JMeter variable into .jtl results file using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property, in order to enable it just add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
sample_variables=num1,num2
```

and the values will be added to .jtl file.

Comment: out.write("\t"); did not work.  so I tried following code but it is not writing anyhting to the csv file-  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
 line_num1 = vars.get("line_num");
 
log.info("number is" +line_num1);


 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\5CB4024KNM\\Desktop\\MOBI\\mobi\\r.csv", true);
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
 out.write(vars.get("line_num"));
 out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
 out.close();
 fstream.close();